# Where to get latest runtime (version 5.5.216.0 of MicrosoftAzureServiceFabric.cab)

Tags: azure-service-fabric

The Service Fabric runtime cab used to be part of the standalone package, but appears to have been removed in the latest release. As far as I can tell, the new DownloadServiceFabricRuntimePackage.ps1 script should do the job of retrieving it when creating a cluster. However, running the new script fails with the below error. Where can I manually download the latest CAB please?

"Runtime package cannot be downloaded. Check you internet connectivity. If the cluster is not connected to the internet use DownloadServiceFabricRuntimePackage.ps1 script to download the latest package. Then run CreateServiceFabricCluster.ps1 -ClusterConfigur
ationFilePath  -FabricRuntimePackagePath  to create the cluster. Exception thrown : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find Fabric resource file ClusterSettings.json in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric
\bin\fabric\fabric.code C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager\v4.0_5.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35.
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.Common.StandaloneUtility.FindFabricResourceFile(String filename)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.Common.StandaloneUtility.GetGoalStateUri()
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.d__10.MoveNext()"

Thanks,
Hans

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the needed link on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=839354).

Hans

Comment: Are you installing on a cluster with no net connection? I tried yesterday and couldn't get it to work, ended up giving the node I was installing it on net access :(

Comment: As a side note, I should also mention that I was not able to run the script to create a cluster without first uninstalling "Microsoft Service Fabric" from control panel. It kept complaining it couldn't find some Internal.Strings assembly until I did. I posted the full explanation on the Service Fabric forum.

Comment: @HansRavnaas Thanks! - I also had to uninstall the Service Fabric SDK.